# как я могу получить PID процесса запускаемого из .jar файла, в коде С#?

Tags: c#

Вот что я делаю

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\inatoff\Desktop\test.jar";
process.Start();
```

а test.jar в свою очередь запустит Pipeline process_id которого мне нужно получить
единственное что позволяет получать это костылина такого типа:

```
var time = process.StartTime;
Thread.Sleep(200);
var wantedProcessId = Process.GetProcesses().First(p=>p.StartTime==time);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, многоуважаемое сообщество.

Answer (score 1):

Ну зная родительский процесс вы всегда можете получить дочерние процессы, например так:

```
var parrentProcess = Process.Start(@"C: \Users\inatoff\Desktop\test.jar");

// NOTE: Process Ids are reused!
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM Win32_Process " +
    "WHERE ParentProcessId=" + parrentProcess.Id);

List<Process> jarProcesses = new List<Process>();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
  jarProcesses.Add(Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"])));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922725/monitor-child-processes-of-a-process)

Comment: а если у родителя 200 таких процессов? а мне нужен именно этот, скажем так - получить его PID во время запуска